# How can I get the Time[0] in different timeframes?

Tags: mql4

How can I get the Time[0] in different timeframe? I am only using one chart, Thank you in advance for helping.

for example, my current open chart is in 1H timeframe,
I want to get the candle open time in 1H timeframe, in 30M timeframe and 15min timeframe, without changing the timeframe of current open chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get **Time** value for the bar of specified timeframe use `iTime()` function.

Example (both alerts have same results):

```
Alert("Time[0]: ", Time[0]);
Alert("iTime[0]: ", iTime(Symbol(), PERIOD_CURRENT, 0));
```

For specified **timeframe** use [enum timeframes](https://docs.mql4.com/constants/chartconstants/enum_timeframes).

Check also [iTime docs](https://docs.mql4.com/series/itime).